# VS Code MSSQL Extension: Align columns and headers by default?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code

I am using the `mssql` extension for VS Code, which is amazing and makes my workflow a lot smoother. Hats off to the developers.

When I run a query, I can align the column widths of the headers and the remaining columns of the resulting output by clicking-and-dragging the horizontal border of any one column header by a teensy bit.

Is there any way to make this alignment happen automatically without me doing anything?

Answer (score 0):

This misalignment was the result of my setting a non-default font size for the output. I removed this setting and now the header widths are aligned with the column widths.